# Que signifie l’expression : « Avoir du nez » ?

Tags: expressions

Que signifie exactement l’expression : « Avoir du nez » dans une discussion?

Avoir de l’intuition ou bien être une personne curieuse?

Answer (score 6):

*Avoir du nez* signifie avoir un bon instinct, une bonne intuition. C'est équivalent à *avoir du flair*.

Une expression avec *nez* qui évoque la curiosité peut être *fourrer son nez* quelque part, qui signifie "se mêler d'affaires qui ne vous regardent pas, être indiscret".